# Laravel try catch not working, cant catch exception from a package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-exceptions

I am using a package https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap to read email from mail server, I have the following code

```
$folder = Storage::disk('local')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
try {
    $mailbox = new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxxxx', $folder);    
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    return 'rroor';
}
```

but is not catching error, I want to log the error if login fails.

The following code is throwing the exception

```
if(!$result) {
    $errors = imap_errors();
    if($errors) {
        if($throwExceptionClass) {
            throw new $throwExceptionClass("IMAP method imap_$methodShortName() failed with error: " . implode('. ', $errors));
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I catch this exception on my controller method ?

see the error page

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have the class constructor in the try...catch. I looked at the repo and it doesn't appear to throw that exception from the constructor. https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap/blob/master/src/PhpImap/Mailbox.php#L33

Is there more to your code that may be calling this part of the code https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap/blob/master/src/PhpImap/Mailbox.php#L148?

I think you need to wrap more of your code into the try...catch that's missing from your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    $folder = Storage::disk('local')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $mailbox = new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 
   'xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxxxx', $folder);    
}
catch(\Throwable $e) {
   return 'error';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use PhpImap\ConnectionException;

//....

$folder = Storage::disk('local')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
try {
    $mailbox = new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'xxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxxxx', $folder);    
}
catch(ConnectionException $e) {
    return 'rroor';
}
```

Or edit your App\Exceptions\Handler;

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \PhpImap\ConnectionException\ConnectionException) {
       //add log
       return 'error';
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: `instanceof \PhpImap\ConnectionException`